# Postgres Group By with additional condition

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm having problem with I would think simple query.
I'm trying to group users, by given name so in result I get something like this:

```
| name_1 | 0 |
| name_2 | 0 |
| name_3 | 2 |
| name_4 | 0 |
| name_5 | 0 |
```

And I achieve this with this query:

```
SELECT r.name, count(ur.user_id)
FROM public.user_roles as ur
RIGHT JOIN roles as r
ON ur.role_id = r.id and r.company_id = 1
GROUP BY r.name
```

Now I want to add another condition, and another joined table. `UserRole` contains reference to `Role` and `User`, so my query looks like this:

```
SELECT r.name, count(ur.user_id)
FROM public.user_roles as ur
RIGHT JOIN roles as r
ON ur.role_id = r.id and r.company_id = 1
LEFT JOIN users as u
ON ur.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.status != 'deleted'
GROUP BY r.name, u.status
```

But instead of getting table as on the beginning. I get something like this(according to if I look for deleted or active user)

`| name_3 | 2 |` <- for active

`[]` <- for deleted

And I want to achieve something like first table from the post. Any idea?

`EDIT`
Expected result would be:

```
| name_1 | 0 |
| name_2 | 0 |
| name_3 | 0 |
| name_4 | 0 |
| name_5 | 0 |
```

Comment: If you remove "WHERE u.status != 'deleted' " do you get what you want?

Comment: @Kendle No. I'm interesed only in Users who are not 'deleted'. With my first query I get all users

Answer (score 0):

You have to move `u.status` in the join like this. If you don't, the `left join` is considered as an `inner join`

```
SELECT r.name, count(ur.user_id)
FROM public.user_roles as ur
RIGHT JOIN roles as r
ON ur.role_id = r.id and r.company_id = 1
LEFT JOIN users as u
ON ur.user_id = u.id and u.status != 'deleted'
GROUP BY r.name, u.status
```

Comment: In this case I get the same result as in first query.
`and u.status != 'deleted'` is not working correctly no matter if it's `deleted` or `active` it returns same result.

Comment: Please post create, insert script and expected result